# how to select two rows in mysql and view by get id

Tags: php, mysql, get

suppose i have 3 buildings

```
Building 1
Building 2
Building 3
```

i select building 1
after that my current code show all floor of building 1

after that i have all floors

```
floor 1
floor 2
floor 3
floor 4
```

then i select floor 1

now i have

```
flat 1
flat 1
flat 1
flat 2
flat 2
flat 2
flat 3
flat 3
flat 3
flat 4 
flat 4
flat 4
```

this is showing wrong because  it is showing all buildings of flats

and i want building 1 floor 1 flats only

how can i do this please help me 
thanks

and i think some changes to here in link but i dont know how can i do this

```
echo "<td><div align='center'><a href=\"floors.php?id=" . $row['buildingname'] . "\" class=\"style2\"><img src='images/floor.gif' width='60' height='90'></a><p>" . $row['floorno'] . "</p><div></td>";
```

i want like this 
link like this

floors.php?id=building1&floor1

after that all flat is showing perfect

floors.php?id=" . $row['buildingname'] ." and " . $row['floorno'] ."

this is complete code
and this is showing floors of selected building by get id

```
<?php

     $id = $_GET['id'];

        $max_results = 8;

        $from = (($page * $max_results) - $max_results);


        if(empty($_POST)) {
                      $query = "SELECT * FROM floors  where buildingname='$id' ORDER BY floorno ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results ";
        } 
        $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        $count=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                if($count%4==0)
                {
                echo "<tr/>";
                echo "<tr>";
                }

                echo "<td><div align='center'><a href=\"floors.php?id=" . $row['buildingname'] . "\" class=\"style2\"><img src='images/floor.gif' width='60' height='90'></a><p>" . $row['floorno'] . "</p><div></td>";

                $count++;


        }



        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>"; 
        echo '</div>';
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider re engineer your database for using this, like building have many floor and floor have many flat. After you done it just inner join your tables to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Selecting the flats

Ok, I assume you have this table:

```
+----------+-------+--------+------+
| Building | Floor |  Flat  | .... |
+----------+-------+--------+------+
|  Elm St. |     1 |  Left  | .... |
|  Elm St. |     1 |  Right | .... |
|  Elm St. |     2 |  Left  | .... |
| 5th Ave. |     1 |  Left  | .... |
+----------+-------+--------+------+
```

So if you just want the flats in the second floor of the Elm Street Building to show up, you have to specify it like that:

```
SELECT * FROM floors WHERE building='Elm St.' AND floor = 2
```

#### Creating Links

If you want a link directing you to let's say `flats.php`, this script needs the building id and the floor, so you need to send them in seperate GET variables:

```
Request:
flats.php?building=Elm St.&floor=2

PHP + MySQL:
$bid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['building']);
$fid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['floor']);
SELECT * FROM floors WHERE building='$bid' AND floor = '$fid'
```

#### Putting it all together

This all is very basic and will be covered in most tutorials on mysql and php! So read a bit more about this topics.

Secondly there are security issues, thats why you need `mysql_real_escape_string` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: listen now i have this link floors.php?id=building1&floor1 link have floor and building name now how can i connect in mysql query $query = "SELECT * FROM floors  where buildingname='$id' And floorno='i want here floor no how can i do this' ORDER BY floorno